# Methods for distributed persistence in Karaf with Cellar

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf

I have recently been looking into using [Apache Karaf Cellar](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/cellar.html) in order to create a distributed application. It looks promising, but i am having a problem finding a persistence strategy that goes in like with the distributed mindset.

Cellar has the distributed memory handled, but what i need is a way for all my nodes to persist data to disk in an orderly way.

Preferably, i would like a persistence store alongside each Karaf instance, that can persist and retrieve objects and synchronize among themselves. The only way i have found to do this is to create a [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) instance alongside all my Karaf isntances and collect them in a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/).
There are a couple of shortcommings with this approach however, most of all that there a manual steps in adding the new MongoDB instances to the set.

SO: Is there a proper OSGi way to do persistence to disk in a synchronized manner? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Not really a question related to osgi. It's a general issue you have with a distributed system where you need to access a single resource from different systems.

Comment: Yes i agree. What i want to know is if there is some brilliant way to solve the problem with a number of, for example, Karaf instances running a distributed system. I won't have heavy writing to the system, so synchronous replication should be OK, i "just" want the datastore to live inside the container so everything can be installed and configured as one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "proper OSGi way" to solve this issue. 
But with the given technology stack you already looked at it might be possible to do.

> i "just" want the datastore to live inside the container so everything can be installed and configured as one

In that case I'd say Apache Karaf + Apache Karaf Cellar in combination with the already used Hazelcast Map of Cellar is the solution for you. With any application running inside this scenario you are able to use the provided Hazelcast instance. Which will make sure all your custom data is synced in a "hazelcast" way.

In the end it boils down to use some technique/tools that will run in any environment to solve the requirements to distribute certain data between different nodes.
In this case I'd suggest to use Cellar and Hazelcast, as it's easily usable. 
But there might be other solutions available, that I'm not aware of right now.

*EDIT*:
To have a distributed system that does store data from any node you either need to rebuild existing techniques like Cassandra, or just use a Cassandra Database.

The other way would be to have different Cluster Groups with Cellar, one which only consists of a Service that talks to a Database, this service will provide JTO Objects from this Database. This service can be distributed to the other cluster group by means of the Cellar mechanism (Remote Services). From there on talking to the single DB can be achieved by referencing the OSGi service for storing data to the database from any node and in fact those services are only available on one node from another cluster group.

Comment: That's true for the in-memory data, but the golden question is: What on earth do i do when i need to persist something to disk. I would love to be to be rid of database clusters and just have a datastore living in each Karaf instance, and have those synchronize amongst themselves. Doesn't such a solution exist?

Comment: erf, again this is nothing special concerning OSGi in general or Karaf. It's something which is true for any distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency in this case should be handled programmatically. 
Existing objects can be locked via hazelcast-map as described by Achim. 
New objects to persist depend on your originating interface / service (WebService-Request, File-consumption, etc.) Only for file-consumption you have to ensure that the file is only processed once.

Replication mechanisms for database clusters is covered by the database providers (even by MySql (; )